# Cookie path with NGINX reverse proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, nginx, cookies

I have three different applications running behind a NGINX reverse proxy.

They all have a login GUI, which uses the same authentication API. Authentication is based on cookies.

My problem is now, that the pathes of the cookies are set differently depending on which GUI is used to login.

The authentication API, actually sets the cookie-path to /, but I assume it is the NGINX proxy, which is overwriting that depending on the location.

Is there a way to set the path of the cookies to /, regardless which GUI is used?

This is how my NGINX configuration looks like:

```
http {
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location = / {
            rewrite / /admin;
        }

        location /admin/ {
            proxy_pass  http://localhost:9001/;
        }

        location /app/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3100/;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass  http://localhost:3000/;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 1**:
I have tried to add

```
proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
```

as described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/619297/session-lost-in-tomcat-uing-nginx-as-proxy), but it didn't help. The path of the cookie is still /admin or /app

Answer (score 4):

The directive proxy_cookie_path is for sure the solutions for the described problem.

(I just found out that my cookie wasn't set from the serverside API but on the client side. So the problem wasn't the NGINX config.)

So for the record:

```
proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
```

should do the trick if the cookie is set from serverside.
For more information about the directive, see [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cookie_path).

Comment: Confused by the answer. You state "for sure the solutions for the described problem." and at the end "should do the trick if the cookie is set from serverside". But before that you state "my cookie wasn't set from the serverside". So the solution isn't the answer to your problem? I have the same problem and "proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;" does not solve it. Care to clarify?